# Errors in computation of blockchain algorithms, are detectable?

Tags: mining, error

There is a class of fault-tolerant methods named Algorithm Based Fault Tolerance (ABFT), which augments input data with redundancy. Then if any errors occurs when those data are processed, just be inspecting the output (and the redundant information) you can tell with good confidence if the results are correct or not.

- Is there similar method with small overheads to detect if there are
  computational errors while the processor (e.g. mining machine) runs
  blockchain related algorithms?